# Can I travel spontaneously on a Schengen Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

If I travel from the UK to the Netherlands and plan to go somewhere else in the Schengen area, what are the requirements? Would I have to return to the original country where I applied for the visa or can I fly back from that other country?

Comment: What are the details of the visa (type, validity dates, duration, number of entries...). What was the original plan (in terms of reason and duration) and what is the new plan (in terms of reason and duration in the different countries)? If the visa is a multiple-entry visa, is this your first visit?

Answer (score 15):

Most Schengen Type C visas allow you to visit any country in the Schengen Area, but bear in mind:

- That you should respect the validity dates of the visa
- That you should respect the duration of the visa
- That you should respect the 90/180 rule
- That you should respect the number of entries of the visa (for instance if you travel from the Netherlands to Spain via the UK, you will exit and re-enter Schengen, so you need 2 entries for that)
- If this is a single-entry visa, or the first trip on a multiple-entry visa, you should make sure the main reason for your trip is still the one you had on your application.

  For instance if you had planned to stay a week in the Netherlands for business, and add 3 days in Germany for tourism, that's absolutely not a problem (provided you're still within the limits of the visa).

  If you had planned to go on holiday for 3 days in the Netherlands, but suddenly decide to spend two more weeks in Germany, that may raise issues.

You can enter and exit via any country you want.

Also remember that you still must be able you fulfil all criteria for your visit: have a way to return home (ideally a return ticket, or the necessary funds to pay for it), have the required funds to support yourself, have travel insurance for the whole trip, etc.

Comment: Also 'That you should respect the **valid for** field of the visa' and: you may enter, stay and leave from any country listed in the **Valid for** field of the visa.

Answer (score 8):

Two issues come together:

- With a Schengen visa, you are allowed to make minor **adjustments to your itinerary** after the visa is issued, within the duration and validity limits. That can include entering a country that was not on the list, or leaving through it.
  Typical example, you had planned to travel to Germany via France, but you change flights to travel via the Netherlands instead. Different country of entry, still recognizably the same premise.
- With a Schengen visa, you are not allowed to **misrepresent your itinerary** during the application.
  Typical examples would be adding bogus information to make a different country responsible for your application, a practice known as 'visa shopping.'

Your problem may be to convince authorities that an adjustment *after* the application was not a misrepresentation *during* the application. The problem may come up with your *next* visa. The magnitude of this problem will depend on your visa history, your nationality, and your residence. If you are a non-UK-national with ILR in the UK, you would probably be seen as relatively low risk, compared to some other applicants.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's not one of the rare cases of a Schengen visa with limited territorial validity, the visa allows you to travel freely within the whole Schengen area. And it doesn't matter from which country you leave the Schengen area.

Comment: Also, doesn't matter which country you enter from, as long as you disclose that in the application.

Comment: While this answer is right in theory, in practice the more details you need to give to get your visa, the more you have to keep to the plans you made and applied on. Not going to the country you applied from can result in a lot of difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

A Schengen visa is always valid for the entire Schengen Area (unless it has limited territorial validity - look at the visa sticker). That being said, a foreigner should apply at the consulate of the country in which they plan to spend most time. If you plan to visit only Spain and Portugal and you submit these plans in your visa application at the consulate of Spain, you could face problems if you later change your plans and want to spend entire time in Finland. There have been instances of foreigners being turned back for such reasons (not because such visa isn't valid for Finland - it is, but the immigration officials might think you lied in your application, which makes you inadmissible). However, that's apparently not your case.

Anyway, once inside the Schengen Area, you can move freely across all internal borders. Most importantly, you can also leave the Schengen Area anywhere, incl. from a country not originally included in your visa application travel plan. As long as you're not overstaying, it won't cause any problems.

Comment: _the country where they plan to enter the Schengen Area or where they plan to spend most time_ That's incorrect, one should apply at the consulate of the country which is the main reason for their visit, and if there is a tie, then where they plan to spend the most time. The country where they plan to enter the Schengen Area is irrelevant.

Comment: Not correct: *A Schengen visa is always valid for the entire Schengen Area*. Only when, in the **Valid for** field of the visa, **Schengen Countries** (language dependent of the issuing country) has been entered is the visa valid for the entire Schengen Area. With any other entry then the visa has been issued with limited territorial validity.

Comment: I applied in Czech embassy and entered via germany and exited via france. This is not true. You have to apply at the country where you intent to spend maximum time.

Comment: @AnishSheela, thanks for the edit. However, the immigration official might consider your application fraudulent if you enter the Schengen Area far away from your stated planned itinerary. In case of Czechia vs. Germany, it's not suspicios. In case of Spain vs. Finland, it **could** be. But you're right in principle.

Comment: @MarkJohnson limited territorial validity only applies to the Type D visas. A holder of such visa is granted longer stay in stated countries. But the visa can still be used in the entire Schengen Area. In all other Schengen countries, the 90/180 rule applies.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko We submit an itenary in the embassy when applying visa. However weird it is, if we follow the itenary, we won't have a problem.  The embassy won't give you visa and will ask to apply at proper embassy if you apply at wrong embassy.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko There are many reasons for a visa with limited territorial validity, of which you only named one (when a Passport of a country not recognised by all states - only those countries that recognise it will be listed). They remain, nevertheless, type C visas. Otherwise Article 25 of the Visa Code would explicidly state that a visa with limited territorial validity are type D visas.

Comment: @AnishSheela that's correct. In my answer I referred to the situation in which the holder **does not** follow their own itinerary used for visa application.

Comment: @MarkJohnson alright, edited.